# SQLite query in Android not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to write a query, but my aplication crashes and I don't see the reason, I have function like this

```
public Cursor getPraktikum(long sat, String dan) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME_NAME}, COLUMN_NAME_DAY + "=" + dan + "AND" + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_START + ">=" + sat + "AND" + COLUMN_NAME_END + "<" + sat + ")", null,
                    null, null, null, null); 
      // Cursor mCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT" + COLUMN_NAME_NAME + "FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + "WHERE" + COLUMN_NAME_DAY + "=" +dan + "AND" + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_START + ">=" + sat + "AND" + COLUMN_NAME_END + "<" + sat + ")", null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

As you see I tried both query and rawQuery versions none work.
"Sat" and "Dan" are gained like this.

```
Calendar kalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int sat = kalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int dani= kalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    String dan=new String();
    if(dani==3) {
        dan ="Utorak";
    }
    DatabaseHelper dbi=new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    dbi.open();
  //  Cursor c=dbi.getTermin(1);
   Cursor cu = dbi.getPraktikum(sat,dan);
 /*   if (cu.moveToFirst())
        DisplayContact(cu); */
    dbi.close();
}
public void DisplayContact(Cursor c)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n",

            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I was leading myself with the function whose getTermin(long rowId) which works and goes like this

```
public Cursor getTermin(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
                            COLUMN_NAME_NAME, COLUMN_NAME_DAY, COLUMN_NAME_START, COLUMN_NAME_END}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

I've googled everything but I just can't seem to find why function getPraktikum isnt' working and getTermin does, please help!

Comment: Look at the logcat, read the error.

Comment: Can you show log your query string when sqlite excute?

Comment: It says there's no such column as "Utorak" but I don't understand, it's in a database. `db.open();
        long id = db.insertTermin("PRAKTIKUM 1", "Ponedjeljak", "16", "17");
        id = db.insertTermin("PRAKTIKUM 2", "Ponedjeljak", "17", "18");
        id = db.insertTermin("PRAKTIKUM 3", "Ponedjeljak", "16", "18");
        id = db.insertTermin("PRAKTIKUM 4", "Utorak", "13", "14");
        db.close();`

Comment: 09-15 13:35:14.178  15894-15894/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: Utorak
09-15 13:35:14.199  15894-15894/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash And later says Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Utorak (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT name FROM termini WHERE day=Utorak AND ( start_time>=13 AND end_time<13 )

Comment: Responses like this should really be edited into the question .. they're much easier to read there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are not writing the queries right. You need to put spaces into your strings

```
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME_NAME}, COLUMN_NAME_DAY + "=" + dan + "AND" + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_START + ">=" + sat + "AND" + COLUMN_NAME_END + "<" + sat + ")", null,
                    null, null, null, null);
```

Try changing, "AND" to :

```
COLUMN_NAME_DAY + " = " + dan + " AND " ~~
```

Comment: I changed it to        `db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME_NAME}, COLUMN_NAME_DAY + "=" + dan + " AND " + "( " + COLUMN_NAME_START + ">=" + sat + " AND " + COLUMN_NAME_END + "<" + sat + " )", null,
                        null, null, null, null);`

It's still now working

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, string values must be quoted:

```
... WHERE day = 'Utorak' ...
```

However, using strings this way leads to formatting problems when the string contains quotes.
A better way is to use parameters:

```java
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME_NAME},
         COLUMN_NAME_DAY + "= ? AND" +
         "(" + COLUMN_NAME_START + ">=" + sat + " AND " +
               COLUMN_NAME_END   + "<"  + sat + ")",
         new String[]{ dan },
         null, null, null, null);
```